# What Bash feature is used when replacing strings in a variable within curly brackets?

Tags: bash, text-processing

In https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12174947/removing-part-of-a-filename-for-multiple-files-on-linux#12175160, a piece of sample code uses a Bash feature where string manipulation on the contents of a variable is done without explicitely calling `sed` or any similar tool:

```
 mv "$filename" "${filename//thisstringgetsremoved/}"
```

What Bash feature is being used here, and does it call sed in the background or does it rely on a built-in implementation of regular expressions (if so, what flavour of regular expressions can be used here)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html), and it’s built in to the shell, it doesn’t rely on `sed`. The pattern isn’t a regular expression, it’s [a filename pattern](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html).

Basic parameter expansion is [specified by POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02); the bash implementation adds a few extensions.